# How To create a default ActionFilter (OnActionExecuting) and override with attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using ASP.NET MVC4, I want to create an action filter attribute like this:

```cs
public class ForceHttps : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {...
```

What I want is, to assign that attribute to controllers that I want HTTPS, and for all others, I want to have another `OnActionExecuting` that forces HTTP.

I could decorate every other controller with `[ForceNoHttps]` and that would work, but my preference is to have the default be `[ForceNoHttps]`, and only when I specify `[ForceHttps]` does this method get executed and not the other one.

So, I want it to execute one or the other, not both.  That is,

```
if {[ForceHttps] is on controller}
  Force the page to https
else
  Force the page to http
```

Make sense? Can I do this?

Comment: just to make sure I understand, you want to set certain actions to use https and make sure that other actions don't inherit automatically?

Comment: @Peter Kelliner, Why don't you have two base controllers as HttpController and HttpsController and inherit all your http controllers from HttpController  and all your HTTPS controllers from HttpsController. these HttpController and HttpsController will inherit from Controller and you have have your OnActionExcuteing overide method here to handle url redirect.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this:

```cs
public class NotHttpsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            string redirectUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.
                 Request.Url.ToString().Replace("https:", "http:");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that you have to apply this filter to every Controller/Action that is NOT https.

A way to lessen your programming burden, is to make NotHttps into a global filter by registering it in your global.asax.

```cs
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
    filters.Add(new NotHttpsAttribute()  { Order = 0 });
}
```

Comment: Dave, If I create a global filter, how can I get that filter "not" to run on the controllers I tag with Https attribute?

Comment: @PeterKellner, thats a good point. I was thinking by using `[RequireHttps]` with a lower priority (e.g. order=2) to assure is runs **after**, but now that I think about it, I can't be sure what order global filter gets :(

Comment: @PeterKellner, apparently you can set order for Global Filters (see my edit). Now, I suspect, that as long as your `[RequireHttps(Order = 1)]` always runs **after**...